# My C# application is intermittently hanging when running on localhost

Tags: c#, localhost, freeze

Is there one kind soul out there who has the time to help me figure out why my application is intermittently hanging (and hopefully how to fix it)? I'm running a web program from VS2015 that accesses a SQL Server database. Sometimes I'll click on a link on my webpage and everything works fine. Other times, though, the little circle just spins forever, and it never comes back. It doesn't seem to be related to the database because one time I caught it hanging on a call to `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);`

I'm running the website in IIS Express on localhost on a Windows 10 laptop (16GB & plenty of disk). I also have ReSharper if anyone thinks that can help me diagnose the problem. I've been fighting with this for days and have no idea what else to do but hope that someone here will have pity on me.

> Re: D Stanley's comments: "Do you have any logging? Can you run it in the debugger to see where it's hanging? Is there anything in the system event logs?"

There is logging, but only on caught exceptions. Nothing that will help the hang situation. I can run it in the debugger, but when it's hung I can't see where it's hung (it's in External Code). The Event Log does report a "perflib" error when I run the program. I can post that info if you think it would help.

More info. I installed Fiddler. When the application is hung, Fiddler is still going to town. The "Process" it's showing is "scriptedsandbox64", which is doing I/O and consuming CPU time.

Comment: Do you have any logging?  Can you run it in the debugger to see where it's hanging?  Is there anything in the system event logs? (Add answers to your question, not in comments)

Comment: That's not true "the circle spins forever and never comes back" or rather, this would be suspicious. Normally, a web request should either timeout on a server (and return 5xx to the client) or timeout at the client. I suggest you configure a proxy at the client (Fiddler, Burp) and see what really happens between the client and the server.

Comment: Ok, technically, it never comes back in the time I give it (which is upwards of an hour sometimes). I'm afraid I don't know how to configure a proxy, do you have a pointer?

Comment: A request will not time out if debug is set to true in web.config. Try changing the debug to false to allow the request to time out. From the exception, see if the stack trace gives you better information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my hanging problem was to use Local IIS instead of IIS Express. Once I figured out how to set up the website for localhost and began running with Local IIS my hangs disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add lots more log messages to your code, something like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") "Starting xxx"
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") "Finished xxx"
```

where xxx is a name for some chunk of code. You suspect the problem is in external code, so wrap all those calls.

You can then see where the application spends excessive time. Once you have found the right area, then perhaps add more logging to focus in on the problem.

Comment: This is a very large application, and I really don't know where all it hangs (it seems to be in different places). I think randomly adding logging all over the place would be an exercise in futility.

Comment: More futile is just to speculate where can exist an error without any code or knowledge about where the program hangs up.